# UIAlertView crashes on iOs 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview, alert, rating

I have the following code that is called when my "gameover scene" appear for the 3rd time:

```
_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!!!\n\n"
                  "bla bla vla!"
                  message:NULL
                                           delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"No, thanks"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Rate",@"Later",nil];
if (![settings boolForKey:@"ShouldNotRateLater"]) {
         [_alert show];
}
```

It started crashing on iOs 7 and it didn't happen in iOs 5 or 6.

I have already tried:

```
//[_alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; or

/*dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [_alert show];
             [_alert release];
         }); */
```

Those are tips I saw in other threads but it doesn't work for me.

Also, running the NSZombie I got the following log:

```
[UIImage isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16da1dd0
```

Does any one know what I am doing wrong?

Many Thanks

Comment: What's the stack trace for the crash? What's the error message for the crash?

Comment: Why have you got a title with newlines and an empty message? Why not put some of your title string as your message? (Also, you shouldn't be passing NULL there anyway...)

Comment: Hello! I get a Exc_Bad_Acess code = 1. I tried as nil for the message instead of NULL and it still doesn't work

Comment: The crash is on this line [_alert show];

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code like this and it works:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!!!\n\n"
          "bla bla vla!"
                                    message:NULL
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"No, thanks"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Rate",@"Later",nil];
[alert show];
```

So either your _alert is declared the wrong way (weak vs. strong as @Ramshad suggests) or there is something wrong with your `![settings boolForKey:@"ShouldNotRateLater"]`

Please post the error that you get.

Comment: Why would the weak vs strong issue manifest on iOS7 but not on iOS6?

Comment: My code works for me when I call it in the first time the gameOver screen appears, but it doesn't work when I call it in the 4th or 5th time. I tried to run the code without without![settings boolForKey:@"ShouldNotRateLater"] and it still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

set `@property` as `strong` instead of `weak`

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIAlertView *alert;
```

Comment: 1) There is no indication there is a property let alone whether it is weak or not. 2) Even if there is a property, it isn't being use so this can't be the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using "NULL" for the message argument? The method is expecting and object pointer so the correct way is to use "nil" if you do not want any message.
Maybe that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: There is a difference between correctness and something working==it doesn't crash...but whatever. 
The second part of my post is a hypothesis/suggestion, not a fact. It implies that I am not sure about it, and suggest to test it. If you feel like you need to take away 5 points from me, enjoy it.

Comment: The purpose of up- and downvoting answers is not to take away your rep. points, it's to keep the quality of StackOverflow as high as possible. I downvoted your answer because it doesn't provide useful information, nor an answer to his/her problem. You should have left a comment for that.

Comment: What is not clear on the "maybe" part? I just do not have Xcode with me to test right now. And it is extremely easy to test for the original poster. It is so easy that it is wort hot do on Op's part now, because it might be helpful. Other than wait for me another two hours to test.

Comment: I don't want to start a discussion with you. If it's not a definite answer write it as a comment. No need to get upset if someone down votes your answer, happens to everyone. FYI: The person who down votes an answer also loses rep. points.

Comment: I inserted a message and it still having the same problem.